# "I mean" in past tense narration is not "I meant" but is it the same for other similar construction?

Tags: grammar, commas, past-tense, construction

My question is quite simple:

I have seen a lot of construction that start with "I mean," and here are a few examples:

I mean, you don't have to go to the dance. 
I mean, it wasn't like you were at fault.

Even in past tense, the "I mean" is not "I meant" because it's wrong, obviously. "I meant" is only used when you are implying what you mean about something in the past. But you see, it's quite confusing when I realize about this at first and still not sure about a lot of thing.

What if, when I write a narration in past tense that start with "I swear," like this:

"I swear, he wasn't the one that burned the house."

Would it be "I swear," or "I swore"?

Of course, I can get away with I swore when then construction is as follow: 
I swore that he wasn't the one that burned the house. 
But when comma is involved, it becomes more complex.

Comment: You can in the present swear that something past was true. Or you could say that at that time you swore it.

Comment: Here, _swear_ isn't the framing quotative verb. The narrative will be something like << John says: "I swear, he wasn't the one that burned the house." >> 'I swear' here is probably the pragmatic usage: a veridical pragmatic marker equivalent to 'Truly'.  The whole, in a past timeframe, becomes  << John said: "I swear, he wasn't the one that burned the house." >> You can only convert to a report structure by rephrasing: << John declared forcefully / sincerely that ... >>.

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues getting confused here—tenses, direct vs reported speech, and "I mean" as a filler phrase vs literal meaning. But the central issue is: *One sentence can contain multiple tenses*.

> I'm telling you, I hope I'll never again see such a sight as I saw that day.

I'm "telling" in the present, hoping about the future, and recalling the past.

So in the sentence "I mean, it wasn't like...", it's perfectly okay that "I mean" present and the rest of the sentence is in the past.

A separate issue: In that example, "I mean" is [an idiomatic usage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/I%20mean), emphasizing or simply adding filler. But it doesn't really let itself be cast into past tense and retain the same usage. If "I meant" appears, it is a more literal usage, meaning "My intended meaning was," as in "I meant what I said."

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. Yeah I know about a sentence having multiple verbs is possible. But I'm wondering whether there are others like "I mean" that has similar idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different things going on.

*I mean* is a discourse marker. We use these in speech (and writing — though different ones) to transition the conversation. They are independent of the rest of the sentence.
<sub>[See Cambridge Dictionary — Discourse markers (so, right, okay)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/discourse-markers-so-right-okay)</sub>

*Swear* in *I swear, he wasn’t the one that burned the house* (with or without the comma) is a “performative verb.” *Performative verbs are verbs carried out simply by means of uttering them aloud.* So you promise, as we speak, that he wasn’t the arsonist.
<sub>[See Wikipedia — Performative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_verb)</sub>

You can, of course, use *swear* in a non-performative manner by using other tenses, as in your example: *I swore that he wasn’t the one that burned the house.* There, you are *reporting* the performative action that you took in the past.

Comment: Ohhh! So the reason "I mean" is not past tense is because it's a discourse markers... But I see that "I swear" also having it's V1 used for a completely different reason, huh...